# Is it possible to reboot server from /dev/sdb while RAID 1 rebuilds /dev/sda?

Tags: linux, raid, centos7, mdadm, netboot

I have a dedicated server with a Raid I with `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` in which `/dev/sda` started to fail so I ordered its replacement. After the intervention the server went into rescue mode and I was not given any info from support so I've been trying to get it back up.

I realised even though they replaced the defective hard drive, they didn't bother to copy over the partitions from `/dev/sdb` and add the new hard drive to the `mdadm`. So after doing this myself, I see on `/proc/mdstat` that the recovery is now underway.

```
root@rescue:/mnt/etc# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty] 
md2 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      523200 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md3 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      20478912 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md4 : active raid1 sdb4[1] sda4[2]
      3884961728 blocks [2/1] [_U]
      [====>................]  recovery = 22.4% (872776320/3884961728) finish=254.3min speed=197355K/sec
      bitmap: 1/29 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

I searched on my backups for the appropriate root partition on fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type>  <options> <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md3  / ext4  errors=remount-ro,usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0  0 1
/dev/md2  /boot ext4  errors=remount-ro 0 1
/dev/md4  /home ext4  defaults,usrquota 1 2
/dev/sda5 swap  swap  defaults  0 0
/dev/sdb5 swap  swap  defaults  0 0
proc    /proc proc  defaults    0 0
sysfs   /sys  sysfs defaults    0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot/efi vfat  defaults  0 0
tmpfs   /dev/shm  tmpfs defaults  0 0
devpts    /dev/pts  devpts  defaults  0 0
/usr/tmpDSK             /tmp                    ext3    defaults,noauto        0 0
```

And I made sure it was intact by mounting it from rescue mode.

Then I tried netboot specifying /dev/md3 as the root partition. However when I try to do this the server goes immediately into emergency mode explaining there are some issues with /dev/sda (I imagine because it's still being rebuilt).

```
FAT-fs (sda1): bogus number of reserved sectors
FAT-fs (sda1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
```

I can't pass the login prompt as my root password seems to be unrecognised, so I don't really know what the results of journalctl -xb show, but I imagine the checksum for that hard drive isn't adding up.

The question is, **is there any way to restart the server using the raid but prioritising /dev/sdb while the RAID is being rebuilt?** I know that every reboot makes the mdadm repair process go back to 0% so I'm now trying to be completely sure that if I try something else it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/dev/sda1 /boot/efi vfat  defaults  0 0
```

Your UEFI ESP is not on a disk array. Need this to boot, but it cannot really be an array.

Recover a working file system. Restore it from backup, or reinstall it. Which per [the sysadmin guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-reinstalling_grub_2) is:

```
yum reinstall grub2-efi shim
```

(In theory, you can resync an efi disk with mdadm. Problem is, individual members may be updated by EFI firmware outside the array, so that is super ugly and hacky.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It turns out that even though I copied over all the partitions from `/dev/sdb` to `/dev/sda`, as you point out, `sda1` and `sdb1` aren't part of the disk array, and in fact they should not. I was able to reformat `/dev/sda1` and reinstall the grub. Before that, /dev/sdb1 had the right boot data so I could change the boot entry on `fstab` and boot as usual.